# chmod having no results in specific folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, chmod

I was playing around with `setfacl` and now I can't access /var/www unless I use sudo. When I try to go to my webserver I get a 403 error.

```bsh
user@computer:~$ ls -l /var/www
ls: cannot access '/var/www/{removed}': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/var/www/html': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? html
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? {removed}
```

When I use `sudo`:

```bsh
user@computer:~$ sudo ls -l /var/www
total 8
drwsr-sr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Oct 23 19:19 html
drwsr-sr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Oct 24 08:44 {removed}
```

I tried `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`. I don't get any errors, but there is no change.

How can I get the permissions correct?
Thank you!

**Update**

I just happened to reload the page (from the server) and it's not showing the 403 error any more, it loads the page correctly. `ls` still gives the same results and I still can't access anything in `/var/www` without `sudo`.

Comment: I would also try a `chown -R user:group /var/www/` Operating System Command and then try again.

Comment: [How to remove ACL from a directory and back to usual access control?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/339765/108618)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really have anything in there that I needed to keep. I just deleted `/var/www` and recreated it.